# Get `val` of property from array of objects inside array of objects based on other property of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

```
var arr = [{req: [{type: 'high', val: 1},{type: 'low', val: 2}], other: [{random: 123}]}, {req: [{type: 'cool', val: 1},{type: 'med', val: 3}], other: [{random: 456}]}]
```

how write function using array functions to get value of `val` which is 3 from above array of objects from inside array of objects where `type` is `med`

expected result

```
var result = 3;
```

I tried to use reduce function of array

```
let getRequirementArray = (req, vol) =>
  req.reduce((currentVal, obj) => {
    return obj.type === vol ? obj.val + currentVal : currentVal;
  }, 0);

let getFinalOutput = (arr, vol) =>
  arr.reduce((currentVal, obj) => {
    let { req } = obj;
    let val= getRequirementArray(req, vol);
    return val + currentVal;
  }, 0);
var result = getFinalOutput(arr, 'med');
```

But I am expecting a little smaller function

Comment: can object with key `other` contain type: med ?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, only ```req``` consists ```type``` 'med', if there are more than one 'med' type in ```req``` array of objects, In my case I need to consider only first occurrence of it and return ```val``` property

Comment: I added my answer according to that assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate the array into a single array of objects and then find the object with `type` equal to `med`

```js
var arr = [{req: [{type: 'high', val: 1},{type: 'low', val: 2}], other: [{random: 123}]}, {req: [{type: 'cool', val: 1},{type: 'med', val: 3}], other: [{random: 456}]}]

var mix = [].concat(...arr.map(t => t.req));
var obj = mix.find(x => x.type === 'med');
console.log(obj.val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use every function of Arrays and return false when you got the first value

```js
var value,arr = [{req: [{type: 'high', val: 1},{type: 'low', val: 2}], other: [{random: 123}]}, {req: [{type: 'cool', val: 1},{type: 'med', val: 3}], other: [{random: 456}]}]
arr.every(outerObject => {let desObj = outerObject.req.find(obj => obj.type == "med");if (desObj){value=desObj.val;return false;}return true;   
});
console.log(value);
```